# Loop never stops

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

I have this program for reading char by char a file and print it out on the screen:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char mychar;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("test.txt", "r");
    while((mychar = getc(fp))!=EOF)
        printf("%c", mychar);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints the file but then it continues to loop forever.
Can you help me?

Comment: `unsigned char mychar;` --> `int mychar;`

Comment: Yes, thanks; maybe char is better.

Comment: `char` is wrong. Because `char` is `signed char` or `unsigned char`.

Comment: but it works using char, why shouldn't?

Comment: Actually look at the documentation for `getc`. It returns an `int` actually, and that is the type that should be used.

Comment: It should be able to distinguish between `'\xFF'` and `-1`(EOF)

Comment: [n1570](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) **6.2.5 Types p15** _The three types char, signed char, and unsigned char are collectively called
the character types. The implementation shall define char to have the same range,
representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EOF` have value `-1`
So, why do you declare `mychar` as `unsigned char`?

Please change with this:

```
int main()
{
    int mychar;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("test.txt", "r");
    while((mychar = getc(fp))!=EOF)
        printf("%c", mychar);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```